# Background Won't Turn Black with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code that I have is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="javascript/jquery.js" type="text/Javascript"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="demo"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hi";
        </script>

        <script type"text/javascript">
            $(function()
            {
                $("#demo").css("background", "#000000");    
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The issue that I'm having is that the second block of JS/Jquery doesn't turn the background of the div black. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's because you haven't filled the div with anything that you can't see its color.

Comment: @Musa [`background` works too](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/YVh69/). But you're right, as [per documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/), CSS shorthand properties should be avoided as they're supposed to not be supported. **Edit:** From the docs: `Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported.`, but in fact setting the [`background` does work](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/YVh69/).

Comment: Why don't you combine the two `<script>`'s into one jQuery function? Instead of the `innerHTML` line just use `$("#demo").html("Hi");` in jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#demo").css("background", "#000000");    
}); // <-- You forgot a closing parenthesis
```

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, That was one of the most meaningful edits is the history of mankind! Thank you for that!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing bracket from the document ready handler callback.

```
$(function() {
    $("#demo").css("background", "#000000");    
}); //<-- here
```

Always check the browser's console when dealing with JavaScript. It would have told you instantly that you had a parse error.

Also note that, although some of the answers here do `$(document).ready(function...`, this is synonymous with simply `$(function...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your javascript code under one  tag:

```
<script type"text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hi";
  $("#demo").css("background-color", "#000000");    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Even under one line: `$("#demo").html("Hi").css("background-color", "#000000")`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your function....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#demo").css("background", "#000000");    
});
```

Also you may need to add a width / height to your div.